# How to change font size in an order receipt in Odoo POS?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-view

Using Odoo 11 I want to change the font size on Kitchen Order receipt

```
  <t t-foreach="changes.new" t-as="change">
                    <div size="double-height" t-if="!change.order">
                        <line line-ratio='0.6'>
                            <left><t t-esc="change.name_wrapped[0]" /></left>
                            <right><t t-esc="change.qty" /> <t t-esc="change.unit" /></right>
                        </line>
                        <t t-call="NameWrapped"/>
```

I want to make the name bigger font size

I tried

```
<t t-foreach="changes.new" t-as="change">
                <div size="double-height" t-if="!change.order">
                    <line line-ratio='0.6'>
                        <left><t t-esc="change.name_wrapped[0]" /></left>
                        <right><t t-esc="change.qty" /> <t t-esc="change.unit" /></right>
                    </line>
                    <t t-call="NameWrapped" size='double-height'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The full template look like this

```
<t t-name="NameWrapped">
    <t t-foreach="change.name_wrapped.slice(1)" t-as="wrapped_line">
        <line>
            <left></left>
            <right><t t-esc="wrapped_line"/></right>
        </line>
    </t>
</t>
```

Inherit and update this template, the result should be:

```
<t t-name="NameWrapped">
    <t t-foreach="change.name_wrapped.slice(1)" t-as="wrapped_line">
        <line size='double-height'>
            <left></left>
            <right><t t-esc="wrapped_line"/></right>
        </line>
    </t>
</t>
```

So, you could do something like

```
<t t-extend="NameWrapped">
    <t t-jquery="line" t-operation="replace">
        <line size="double-height">
            <left></left>
            <right><t t-esc="wrapped_line"/></right>
        </line>
    </t>
</t>
```